# Varnish caching POST requests from Server Side Security scanner

Tags: http, varnish, magento2.1

I run a webstore on **Magento ver. 2.1.8** eCommerce platform.

Recently, I came across a issue where front-end of my website was using a completely different colour skin and layout and couldn't figure out why this is happening.

Purging the **Varnish** cache solved the issue for some time as the website would randomly changed the skin again after some time. I had no idea how Varnish was caching the content that should never be displayed.

I also use Acunetix as a **Server Side Scanner** which scans my website every week for any malicious code or gaps in security. I found one of the POST request that it sent:

```
POST /themesettings/index/paneltool/ HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 1193
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=-----Boundary_JTWCAHJSKP
Referer: https://www.domain.co.uk/
Cookie: PHPSESSID=sadfq345r234324dfasd; mage-messages= vespaneltool=a%3A6%3A%7Bs%3A52%3A%22ves_themesettings_general%2Fgeneral_settings%2Fdirection%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22rtl%22%3Bs%3A49%3A%22ves_themesettings_general%2Fgeneral_settings%2Flayout%22%3Bs%3A8%3A%22boxed-lg%22%3Bs%3A52%3A%22ves_themesettings_general%2Fgeneral_settings%2Fmax_width%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22960px%22%3Bs%3A59%3A%22ves_themesettings_general%2Fgeneral_settings%2Fmax_width_custom%22%3Bs%3A8%3A%22gqwtkdks%22%3Bs%3A47%3A%22ves_themesettings_general%2Fgeneral_settings%2Fskin%22%3Bs%3A8%3A%22blue.css%22%3Bs%3A55%3A%22ves_themesettings_header%2Fgeneral_settings%2Fheader_layout%22%3Bs%3A13%3A%22default.phtml%22%3B%7D; _vwo_uuid_v2=EC7CC959823F97596222AB508A6BB8BE|53a815cb661ea346311131469aaeb1c2; PHPSESSID=oaibesqi4980brc3udl1gdrfb0
Host: www.domain.co.uk
Connection: Keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.21 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.21
Accept: */*

-------Boundary_JTWCAHJSKP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="btn-save"

Apply
-------Boundary_JTWCAHJSKP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userparams[ves_themesettings_general/general_settings/direction]"

rtl
-------Boundary_JTWCAHJSKP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userparams[ves_themesettings_general/general_settings/layout]"

boxed-md
-------Boundary_JTWCAHJSKP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userparams[ves_themesettings_general/general_settings/max_width]"

1024px
-------Boundary_JTWCAHJSKP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userparams[ves_themesettings_general/general_settings/max_width_custom]"

12345'"\'\");|]*%00{%0d%0a<%00>%bf%27'ð©
-------Boundary_JTWCAHJSKP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userparams[ves_themesettings_general/general_settings/skin]"

aquamarine.css
-------Boundary_JTWCAHJSKP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userparams[ves_themesettings_header/general_settings/header_layout]"

default2.phtml
-------Boundary_JTWCAHJSKP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="vespanel"

1
-------Boundary_JTWCAHJSKP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="vesreset"

0
-------Boundary_JTWCAHJSKP--
```

The above is the configuration of the **wrong** designed that was cached by Varnish. E.g. `aquamarine.css` is the **wrong** CSS file cached, it should be `red.css`.

Is it possible that after this post request, Varnish cached this settings? Also, what is the best way to overcome this problem? Should I create a rule in Acunetix to avoid this URL? Or create a NginX configuration to block access to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like the following to just force Varnish to not attempt to use (or store into) the cache for POST requests:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.method == 'POST') {
       set req.hash_always_miss = true;
    }
}
```